# Creating the new tag "sexist-language"

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

**Congratulation!** The sexist-language tag suggested by me has been approved as an edit for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107095/what-does-swish-of-skirt-mean-why-is-it-a-sexist-expression) for first time. You all unless 10 users who downvoted this tag and showed their disagreement can use it under any question which is pointing to the sex discrimination in using the English language.

**The reason to create such tag**: I created it as I think it is a necessary details for non-native learners and even native learners to know what words,terms,phrases and expressions convey a sexist usage of English language and what reactions or results it may cause. It is always important for most people having every degree of intelligence to avoid of sexist usages of language in the society nowadays unless persons who want to make themselves isolated and stand in the row of hatred people in the new social classifying. I do not think you can remove social classes from the society but surely it has changed from ridiculous inheritable titles, jobs, situations, wealth and objects to the behaviors, kind of talking and using the language.

**P.S**: Unfortunately the tag has been deleted after suspending me for 3 months because of creating a tag and making this topic! I am still not able to understand the authorities' logic of this site or their bosses but anyway it helps to find how a tag against sexism in language can make waves in a western site not even an eastern one! It seems east and west do meet, and even embrace, on some points! I hope to see this in better examples and for better reasons not oppositely!.. &^) ..

Comment: Sexist language, though possibly a subset, is not identical to offensive language. There are some things that are offensive that are not sexist (like excretory bodily functions or profanity).

Comment: You could make a good case sexist language is taboo but it is also not -all- tabooo language so therefore not a synonym.

So you also created the new tag 'sexist-language'? If so, and it is needed, it will remain.

Comment: 'could' does not equal 'should'!

Comment: chat would be better for this discussion.

Comment: More importantly, sexist jokes may not be offensive in the right context. Equating a kind of perspective with offence disregards irony and is probably not the way to go.

Comment: @Cerberus Sorry but you didn't get the idea. It is not about jokes. It is about sexism in language. You can search it in the Google and find it. And the irony... OMG! It is completely a different matter. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexism. Anyway you can use of sexist language if you like but surely you have to accept its results. It is a kind of sex discrimination not the matter of etiquette. You have to respect the equality between two different sexes and it is not a choice by you like believing in equality between humans in different colors. At finally it is a tag not rule! :)

Comment: Are you actually asking for the creation of a tag, or do you want sexist language treated as inferior?

Comment: @TimLymington It is very clear. It is about why I have suggested creating sexist-language tag.

Comment: *"...unless persons who want to make themselves isolated and stand in the row of hatred people in the new social classifying."* - as judged sexist or inappropriate by whom, you?  This is not the place for that sort of judgemental censorship.  Words are just words.  We need to be able to discuss words and concepts openly to share and explore a deeper understanding that is, in the process, enlightening.

Answer (score 7):

I've removed this tag; it does not describe the content of the question, and therefore is not a good tag. In the case of the question where this tag was approved, its use is borderline - the question *is* actually about the meaning of a given phrase, and whether or not it might be perceived as sexist; nevertheless, this question was already tagged [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) which I feel captures this intent sufficiently.

> It is always important for most people having every degree of intelligence to avoid of sexist usages of language in the society nowadays unless persons who want to make themselves isolated and stand in the row of hatred people in the new social classifying.

Brushing your teeth regularly is important too. You should still avoid adding [brush-your-teeth-dear-reader](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brush-your-teeth-dear-reader) to questions. Tags are intended to help classify questions based on their content, not as a platform for social commentary.

Comment: Sorry but you did it according to your personal idea which shows a lack of knowledge about what sexist-language is. The question clearly is asking if this statement has a sexist meaning or not so I am wondering how you can bravely give such wrong speech here about. You took it completely wrong. As you are a mod with special tools to force your idea to the others surely I cannot do anything against it but I am sure that it is obvious for every user with enough knowledge about this matter. If I were you I has left it for experts. Anyway it is you! The authority! Good luck! :)(

Comment: The question was about the meaning of a specific phrase. The proper place for an explanation of how that phrase might be perceived would be an *answer*, and several of them already exist. Whether or not the phrase is sexist is irrelevant to how the question is tagged.

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite happy to see that Shog9 deleted the *sexist-language* tag.

Any number of prejudices can be implied by word-choice (racism, ageism, pro/anti-religion, etc.). Personally, I don't have much time for questions like [How bad is the use of “n***er” today?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108490/how-bad-is-the-use-of-ner-today) - partly because I think all answers are liable to be subjective, but also because it seems to me they're often asked more in order to engage in protracted debate, rather than to obtain a definitive answer.

We already have [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), as Shog9 points out. More specifically, we've got [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language) (and synonym *pejorative*), which seems perfectly adequate to me.